# Protecting In-App Purchase Hack from Freedom App

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have made extensive search on various websites as well as StackOveflow but couldn't find any working solution.

I have already tried these without success,

[Protecting in-app purchases from Freedom Hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21966369/protecting-in-app-purchases-from-freedom-hack)

[Protection from Freedom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16277467/protection-from-freedom)

Please do not mark this question as duplicate, as it is not. The solutions posted in the previous questions are old and outdated and doesn't solve my problem.

**The Problem**

Its simple and complicated at the same time. My app has in-app purchases and the Freedom app can bypass the in-app purchase with its "FreeCard". What loophole is this app exploiting and how can we solve this?

Any help will be really appreciated.

**Workaround**

I am not getting any answer to this question. I have thought of an workaround where the app will check if the Freedom app is installed in the system, and if so, then it will not let the user initiate any purchase without uninstalling Freedom app.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27117737/435706